# DrawingSurface inside ChildWindow doesn't work

Tags: silverlight, xna, silverlight-5.0

I'd like to show some XNA stuff inside `ChildWindow` which was showed by its `Show()` method.
But the `DrawingSurface`'s Draw event handler is never called.

I suspect the issue somehow relates to using Popup. XNA inside my `UserControl` which is showed as popup also didn't work.

What is the reason that the draw event handler is never called in this situation?